# A question about an instrumentation amplifier and common mode currents

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

Regarding my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351292/a-question-about-remote-ground-sensing-and-its-advantages), an unbalanced(single-ended) source Vs is connected to inputs of an instrumentation amplifier and ground as follows:

[image]

I have seen above connection in many texts.

For simplicity let's assume Vs is DC and common mode voltage Vcm is DC. And all impedances are real and they are resistances.

And regarding the above diagram, let's say the line resistances Rl1=Rl2=100 Ohm. The input impedance of the inAMp is Rx=10 MegOhm. And the source impedance is 200 Ohm.

What I understand is the common mode current **Ic1** loops through the following resistances:

Rs-->Rl1-->Rx

and **Ic2** loops through the following resistances:

Rl2-->Rx

If I'm not wrong the **impedance seen from the hot terminal** is: Rs+Rl1+Rx
and the **impedance seen from the negative terminal** is Rl2+Rx.

**My two questions are:**

**1-)** It seems like Rx>>>Rs in an inAmp because of its buffers, does that mean the source impedance matching is less important than in a difference amplifier? Can Rs in practice can be neglected when using an inAmp this way? Let's say Rs is 50 Ohm and Rx=10Meg, would you still add a series 50 Ohm resistor to the negative terminal? Or would you neglect it because Rx dominates?

**2-)** Look at the third wire at the bottom from the negative terminal of the source to the ground of the inAmp. There is no resistor on that wire. In practice should there be a resistor there not to cause a short circuit?

Edit:

[image]

Comment: do you understand this now? If not, please explain.

Comment: I have to read it and think about it again. That time obviously i didnt get it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem as I see it: -

[image]

- Irrespective of the InAmp being present, if
  electromagnetic interference hit both signal conductors equally, a
  higher interfering voltage will be present on the upper wire because
  it has a bigger impedance due to Rs. This scheme only works when
  there is the same (balanced) impedance in both signal wires.
- Linking remote grounds is (usually) bad because any earth fault
  currents can flow down the cable and pose a problem for the cable
  integrity AND induce voltages in the two signal cables that may add
  to the common mode problem and make the InAmp unable to deal with the
  common mode voltage all the time.
- Both the presense of Rs (unbalanced) and the ground link make
  earth currents flowing in the remote ground connection induce an
  asymmetrical interference onto the two signal wires feeding the InAmp.

Comment: 1-) Rs will affect unbalance but my question about neglecting it when Rx is huge comparing to Rs. Isn't the amount of ubalance is linked to how big is Rx? Imagine Rx is infinite theoretically. Wouldn't the both lines be balanced even there Rs exists?

Comment: 2-) Please see my edit, or here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPbOr.png Now the source is floating I mean it is only grounded at receiver side. Is that still problem? Now it is exactly how they recommend: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEVCr.png you hadnt say anything about this last time.

Comment: @user134429 you are missing the point about Rs imbalancing the system - it does so with respect to EMI hitting the cable - EMI will produce an interfering voltage on the wires that is proportional to impedance to ground and if both impedances are identical then the interfering voltage will be identical on both conductors and the diff amp will ignore those equal voltages. With different impedances it will produce a differential noise. Rx has nothing to do with this effect because it is, in effect an open circuit compared to Rs.

Comment: But what is that total impedance wtr to ground? That is I wanna know. For example for the upper wire is that Rs+Rl1+Rx?

Comment: Oh okay the effect is then about Rs+Rl1 only? Rx shouldn't be in the balancing effect.

Comment: No, of course not. The output from the driving amplifier should be (as a first and useful approximation) regarded as having zero impedance to ground. The signal it produces is relative to ground and it is a voltage signal hence it has extremely low resistance to ground.

Comment: Ok let me know this: When EMI hits to the diagram in my drawing, regardless of Rx = 100 Ohm or Rx=infinite the noise will be the same because we look ate Rs+Rl1 and Rl2 always? Rx is irrelevant always? Im asking because here it says "An instrumentation amplifier is a type of differential amplifier that has been outfitted with input buffer amplifiers, which eliminate the need for input impedance matching" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier

Comment: In your example Rx is massive compared to both cable impedance and Rs so sure, it is nearly always ignored except when you operate with really fast signals (usually 100 kHz minimum).

Comment: Okay so Rx matters that was what I wanted to be sure. How about you also had another comment on the third wire. Maybe my drawing was not o. Do you think if the source is only grounded at the receiver side like my previous question is that okay: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPbOr.png ? I got it from here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEVCr.png

Comment: That wiki article is misleading you: You should, if the input impedance (Rx) is capable of forming a potential divider with your source voltage and its output impedance (Rs), take this into account in order to compensate for resistive potential divider errors.

Comment: The 2nd picture that shows the remote source being powered is fine but, in practise, for many diff amps, if the power feeds are at the source end it won't be a problem providing the difference in ground voltages between source and diff amp are not so great to cause signals that may be outside the common mode range of the input to the diff amp. I urge you to read more on this subject because I can't answer a seemingly endless stream of comments.

Comment: Get a simulator and sim it. LTSpice is free and so is MC11 student version (my personal fave).

Answer (score 0):

1. In practice, the need for impedance matching depends on your signal. Differential amplifiers are available with very high gain-bandwidth product, sometime higher than 5 Ghz. At those speed, impedance control is definitely  required. Instrumentation amplifier are much slower, and rarely go beyond few MHz. By definition, an instrumentation amplifier is a differential amplifier with input buffers. Those buffer Op-amps eliminate the need for impedance matching at low speeds, and give you very high input impedance.
2. I'm not sure what this schematic is trying to show with the \$V_{CM}\$ source. Maybe it's to explain that the ground potential is not exactly the same at different point in the circuit? Were did you got that circuit from? In any case, \$V_{CM}=0\$ V so I think that the wire between the positive terminal of \$V_{CM}\$ and the ground of the amplifier should not be here. Note that instrumentation amplifiers have very high common-mode rejection ratio, so they are very good at rejecting \$V_{CM}\$ while amplifying \$V_S\$.

Comment: You wrote: "eliminate the need for impedance matching at low speeds". I was trying to demonstrate that with Rx>>>Rs in the circuit, is that correct approach for DC-like signals? And the circuit from here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEVCr.png Vcm in mine is common mode voltage between grounds.